# AlertView directing to new UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiview

I'm simply trying to make it so when the first button of an alert view is pressed, another UIView comes up.

So far I've done this but all I get is a black screen after the button is pressed. The second UIView is called ResultsViewController.

Where am I going wrong? Any help appreciated!

At the top:

```
@class ResultsViewController;
ResultsViewController *ResultsviewController;
```

Then:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex == 0){


        UIViewController *ResultsviewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:ResultsviewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    if(buttonIndex == 1){

        [self startRunning];
    }
}
```

Comment: This line `UIViewController *ResultsviewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];` should become `ResultsviewController = [[ResultsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];` And if there is a nib to go with this replace the nil in `initWithNibName:` with the name of that nib file. Please also note that convention says because `*ResultsviewController` is a variable it should start with lower case so it should be `ResultsViewController *resultsViewController;` Variables start with lower case, classes start with upper case

Comment: What are you using to create the ResultsViewController UI? All in code? A separate .xib file? or is it in a storyboard?

Comment: It's storyboard and I linked ResultsViewController.h and .m to it.

Answer (score 1):

These 2 lines are just creating a UIViewControler

```
    UIViewController *ResultsviewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:ResultsviewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

you need

```
   ResultsViewController  * ResultsviewController = [[ResultsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:ResultsviewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Xcode doesn't like it. Is there a typing error before the controller?

Comment: Yes, the first line should be `ResultsViewController *Resultsviewcontroller = [[ResultsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`

Comment: corrected answer - You may be getting a blank screen because normally you would supply a parameter for 'initWithNibName` i.e. `initWithNibName:@"ResultsViewController"` if you xib file is called `ResultsViewController`

Comment: @Flexicoder just remove the nib stuff and use `alloc init` it will search for a nib with the same name and use that if it exists. ... Unless it's created from a storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You declarer `ResultsViewController *ResultsviewController;` and after that you do it again:

```
UIViewController *ResultsviewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

Why is a reason to do that? 
You don't have to call initWithNibName: bundle: if you don't provide nib name.
Replace this line:

```
UIViewController *ResultsviewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

with that one:

```
UIViewController *ResultsviewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
//your code to present result view controller
```

// EXTENDED

Try move the two lines to new method, for example:

```
-(void)openNewView {
    UIViewController *ResultsviewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:ResultsviewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and call it with delay when button is clicked:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(openNewView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

Comment: If I don't declare it at the top then it returns a non-declared identifier. I've made all the changes and i'm still getting a black screen and also some warnings "Incompative pointer types sending 'REsultsCiewController *' to parameter of type "UIViewController *"

Comment: Thanks Greg. The warnings are now gone but it's still only showing a black screen :(. What could be causing such a nonspecific problem?